# Metric tensor and einstein's notations .

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

[image]
Here , $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.
Can someone explain it to me what $F$ is ?
I also don't understand how we can get the unit outer normal in the second para .
Please kindly help me to understand as the text i am referring doesn't say anything regarding what $F$ is .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your whole paragraph, so I hope what I write here is correct.

$\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ with $C^{2, \alpha}$ boundary, that is, $\partial \Omega $ is a $C^{2, \alpha}$ submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$. So for any point $p \in \partial \Omega$, there is an open set $U_p \subset \mathbb R^n$ so that

$$\Omega \cap U_p = \{(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}, F(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb R^n: (x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in V_p \}$$

for some open set $V_p \subset \mathbb R^{n-1}$, and $F$ is in $C^{2, \alpha}(V_p)$. In your case, this $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ is identified with the tangent plane of $\partial \Omega$ at $p$. (That is, $F$ is a local defining function of $\partial \Omega$).

To pick an example, let $\Omega = \{||x|| <1\}$. Then $\partial \Omega = \{||x||=1\}$ is the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ (Obviously a $C^{2, \alpha}$ submanifold). Let $p = (0,\cdots, 0, 1) \in \partial \Omega$. Then choosing

$$U_p = \{ (x_1, \cdots, x_n): |x_1|^2 + \cdots + |x_{n-1}|^2 < 1/2, 0< x_n< 2\}$$

(A cylindraicl open set) and

$$V_p = \{ (x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}): |x_1|^2 + \cdots + |x_{n-1}|^2 < 1/2\} \subset \mathbb R^{n-1}.$$

Then in this case

$$\partial \Omega \cap U_p = \{(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}, F(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb R^n: (x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) \in V_p \},$$

where $F(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) = \sqrt{1- |x_1|^2 - \cdots - |x_{n-1}|^2}$.

For the normal vector, as $\partial \Omega$ is locally parametrized by $F$, then for any $i = 1, \cdots n-1$,

$$(0, \cdots, 0, 1, 0, \cdots , 0, \frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i})$$

is in the tangent space of $\partial \Omega$ at $p$ (The "1" is at the $i$-th component). So one can check directly that $\tilde\nu$ given in your question are perpendicular to all the above tangent vectors and have norm one.